# Shorthand in JS Explanation

Tags: javascript, shorthand

Can someone explain to me this JS shorthand code:

```
   navigator.sayswho = (function(){
      var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
      var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|Trident)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
      if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
      M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
      return M;
   })();
```

The code is working, but I can't understand how it is working, especially this line:

```
M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
```

Comment: It says if M is true, M would be reassigned to [M[1], M[2]] or M would get reassigned to [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];

Comment: It might help if you could explain the context of this function. It's not hard to see what it does, but if we knew *why* the explanation could be improved.

Comment: Got it! That's a good explanation.

Comment: It's good enough. This is to detect the Browser. I just wanted to know what it does, since i don't understand shorthand expressions very good. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
```

means:

```
if (M)
  M = [M[1], M[2]];
else
  M = [N, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
```

More verbosely, it checks to see if "M" is non-empty, which in this case means that the useragent regex matched the actual useragent string. If it's set, then it resets "M" to a new array; effectively it just drops the zeroth element of the original "M".

If it's *not* set, it creates a "fake" array from the application name, the version string, and what appears to be a marker string to indicate that it's an unrecognized useragent.

Answer (score 0):

```
M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
```

here `M` is `boolean type` variable contains true or false

**i.e.**

```
if(M)
   M = [M[1], M[2]];
else
   M = [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
```

Comment: Thank you too, for the explanation. Cheers!